# Virtual server on Arris Modem: “Table FWVirtSrvTable Full”

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding, modem

I have forwarded ports in the past. Never had any issues.

I'm using an Arris TG1672G modem.

Whenever I try to add a virtual server (aka forward a port), I get this "Table FWVirtSrvTable Full" error. And I have no virtual servers added so I don't see how any virtual server table could be "full."

Firewalls are disabled.

I just finished resetting my modem to factory defaults and trying again. Same behavior.

And I've reset the modem and computer multiple times as well.

I have no idea what this error message means. I haven't found it anywhere on the web either.

Comment: is it perhaps because the firewall is disabled? based on teh symbolic constant they use in the message, it does seem that they have tied the ideas of NAT port forwarding with their firewalling (which while slightly inappropriate, is not outlandish, if they wanted to save you the trouble of creating allow rules for forwarded ports).

Comment: No cigar. Enabled firewall (in router) and tried to add again and got same error

Comment: Also the firewall service is stopped in Windows 7

Comment: I tried it with all four combinations of windows and router firewalls on/off and no luck

Comment: Wondering if this issue was ever resolved